# Spring, Hibernate and Maven

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I am learning Spring and Hibernate with Maven. However I am not able to understand the incompatible package issue. There is not such information about which Spring package is compatible with which Hibernate packages. It's like I have to copy the POM file from existing working projects. But I am not convince with this approach. There must be some way to know the compatibility between the dependencies.

Also there is no way to determine which packages are to be included if I wanted to work with Spring and Hibernate.

I am sure there must be a way.  Please help me.

Comment: You can use Spring and Spring Data together. Spring Data framework implement Hibernate functionality and add more features.

Comment: YOu can create a dependency chart using maven. What is your end-goal and share the packages which you want or what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

*I understand you question in that way, that you want to know wich versions to use (not which dependencies to use at all)*

You could have a look at the spring boot poms. (I do not want you to use Spring Boot).

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
```

(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml)

They contain a lot of knoweleg which versions work together well.

For example:

```
<spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven has a plugin that shows dependencies of an artifact in a tree view. You can use it to see dependencies of a `pom.xml`. For example, you can download `pom.xml` from jCenter or Maven Central, and run the following command:

```
mvn -f your-downloaded-pom.xml dependency:tree
```

And it will show something like that:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ spring-orm ---
[INFO] org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE
[INFO] +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.jdo:jdo-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.openjpa:openjpa:jar:2.2.2:compile
....
```

If you want to know the hibernate dependencies for Spring, you can obtain Spring-ORM `pom.xml` for the version you want, for example `4.1.6.RELEASE` and run the following command:

```
mvn -f spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.pom dependency:tree | grep hibernate
```

and you will get this:

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
```

So this is how you can get it.

Hope it helps!